# Acceptable way to mock a javascript ES6 constructor?

Tags: javascript, exception, constructor, mocking

I am trying to find a way to mock a constructor so it throws an error (for unit tests purpose). I got something that seems to work. Here is the working example:

```js
class SomeClass {
    constructor(val) {
        this.value = val;
    }
    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
};

let a = new SomeClass('A');
console.log("a.value=" + a.getValue());

// Make SomeClass acts as if an exception is thrown from constructor
var backupSomeClass = SomeClass;
SomeClass = function(val) {
    throw "problem in pseudo-constructor";
};

try
{
    let b = new SomeClass('B');
    console.log("b.value=" + b.getValue());
}
catch(e) {
    console.log("got error: " + e);
}

// Back to the original class definition
SomeClass = backupSomeClass;

// Test again with original class definition
try
{
    let c = new SomeClass('C');
    console.log("c.value=" + c.getValue());
}
catch(e) {
    console.log("got error: " + e);
}
```

And the corresponding output:

```
a.value=A
got error: problem in pseudo-constructor
c.value=C
```

As I am not familiar with the underlying process of objects creation, I am not sure that this way of doing is acceptable (possible side effects ? unsteadiness ?)

I would appreciate any feedback or piece of advice!

Comment: @myself: even if this seems to work, all goes wrong once the class definition is set in an external file and required in the test file... My fault.

Comment: could explain more what you want to achieve? why even having the need to mock a constructor? if you expect that creating a new Class with missing or wrong properties should throw an error, just create a new one and listen to an error maybe ?

Comment: @Fer To: sorry for the lack of details...
I have two classes, A and B. A depends on B (it builds new B objects).
My goal is to test A, and to check a A object behavior when the B constructor throws an exception.
I know I could achieve this with DI, but I wish I could avoid having to inject the B dependency into the class A...

Comment: What your code does is creating new instances of the same Class "SomeClass". Therefore they all have same constructor. If you want to check for some error handling, testing for a clear case would be better. If you talk about depends, it sounds similiar to "class A extends B" ? Otherwise a third option would be to use prototype and see if you can easily overwrite constructor there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor ? might be this is what you want to do